# jQuery.one() event handler is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Trying to use `jQuery.one()` to disable a button that shows an image of a tree after it is clicked. The `showImage` function works fine, but not `.one`.

Can I not use javascript inside of a jquery event handler?

**html:**

```
<div class="grove">
    <button id="plant" onclick="showImage()">Plant Orange Tree</button>
  </div>

  <div id="orange-tree-template">
    <div class="orange-tree">
      <h2>Tree Name</h2>
      <h3>etc...</h3>
```

**css:**

```
.display-tree-big{
  background: url('../images/tree_big.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:1000px;
  width:1000px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

#orange-tree-template { visibility: hidden; }
```

**javascript**

```
function showImage() {
  var img = document.getElementById('orange-tree-template');
  img.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#plant").one( "click", function() {
    document.getElementById("#plant").disabled = true;
  });
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("#plant")` typo? clearly by the showImage function you know that the `#` doesn't belong there. If you would open your console and view the errors you would see that it returned null, which should prompt you to look at that statement more closely. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null`

Comment: Try `$('#plant').on('click', function () {});`

Comment: @KevinB, hmm? Did I miss something?

Comment: .on and .one should perform identically in this case, considering the problem presents itself on the first click.

Comment: Check. Also, remove the '#' in the `document.getElementById("#plant").disabled = true;`. It's already grabbing by the ID, so the "#" is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issues.

1. You have an inline onclick handler assigned to the button. This will not respect the jQuery.one method, so because of error 2 you could continue to click the button and `showImage` will be called.
2. The function assigned to the click event via `jQuery.one()` **is** being called, however the statement `document.getElementById("#plant")` should not contain `#`, thus the button was not disabled.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#plant").one("click", function() {
    // yes of course you can use JavaScript
    document.getElementById('orange-tree-template').style.visibility = 'visible';
    this.disabled = true;
  });
});
```

```css
#orange-tree-template {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="plant">Plant Orange Tree</button>

<div id="orange-tree-template">
  TEST
</div>
```

Also the [jQuery.one() method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) does not disable anything, it just executes a callback at most once per element per event type.

Comment: Probably because it's just as useful(useless?) as the question.

Comment: @robbmj: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this--your answer helped me fix something I'd spent far too much time on. Clearly, I'm new, so I really appreciate your time all the more on this!